# How to mock response in google test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googletest

I have a tricky situation for gtest mock response. Pseudo code is as below:

.cpp

```
myMethod(resquest, response) {
String name = getName();
response.getResponseType().name() = name;

}
```

.t.cpp

```
    TEST() {
    EXPECT_CALL(mockResponse, getResponseType(_)).WillOnce(,Return ResponseType);
    
    Request request;
    Response response;
    myMethod(request, response);
    
    EXPECT_EQ(...);
}
```

My confusion is here Response is the data structure we wanna write into, but meanwhile also has a getter method. To enable mock the getter method we have to create a `mockResponse` class right? Am I doing the right way in the pseudo code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a mock for the `Response` class, which requires that `getResponseType` is (pure) virtual method. Also, the `EXPECT_CALL` must specify that a reference is returned (notice that `ReturnRef` and not just `Return` is used). Also, `myMethod` shall accept mock by reference (when a copy is made, you won't be able to set expectations because the recorded `EXPECT_CALL`s are counted per object and are **NOT** copied when a mock object is copied).

The code:

```
struct Request{};

struct ResponseType {

    std::string& name() {
        return my_name;
    }

    std::string my_name;
};

struct Response { 
    virtual ResponseType& getResponseType() = 0;
};

std::string getName() {
    return "SOME_STRING";
}

void myMethod(Request resquest, Response& response) {
    std::string name = getName();
    response.getResponseType().name() = name;

}

struct MockResponse : public Response {
    MOCK_METHOD0(getResponseType, ResponseType&());
};

TEST(MyMethodTests, when_myMethodIsCalled_then_responseTypeNameIsSet) {
    ResponseType type;
    MockResponse mockResponse;
    EXPECT_CALL(mockResponse, getResponseType()).WillOnce(testing::ReturnRef(type));
    
    Request request;
    myMethod(request, mockResponse);
    
    EXPECT_EQ("SOME_STRING", type.name());
}
```

On a side note: if `Response` is to be used in a polymorphic manner (via pointer to the base class) it should also have virtual dtor.